# stock for a particular brand

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-markets

Let's say that I'm convinced that "Windows Phone" will grow more popular than "iPhone"/"iOS". I would like to invest my money in this.

The stock market is overwhelming for me. I don't understand how to translate brands/trademarks to a specific stock.

But how can I find out which stock to invest in to make a profit out of this.

I know there are funds that group multiple IT companies. But I am looking for a stock of a specific company. **Simple question:** If you only know the name of the trademark/company, how do you find the name of the matching stock?

What's the easiest way to do this ?

Comment: You'll probably want to research who'd profit from that.

Comment: It's not that there is a company called "Windows Phone" that has its own stock ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the answer by Craig Banach: Sometimes brands are owned by publicly traded companies which have a very diverse product portfolio. In case of Microsoft their stock price and dividend will not be controlled solely by that one product they make but also by their many other products (plus a billion other factors which can influence a stock price). So when you want to bet specifically on the success of Windows Phone then betting on the Microsoft Corporation as a whole might not achieve that goal.

However, you can also try to find companies whose success depends indirectly on the success of the product. That can be suppliers (someone who makes a specific part which is only used for Windows phones), companies which make Windows Phone specific accessories or software developers who make applications which specifically target the Windows Phone ecosystem. When the product portfolio of these companies is far narrower than that of Microsoft they might be more dependent on the success of Windows Phone than Microsoft themselves.

But as always, keep in mind that the success of their products is not the only factor which decides the stock value of a company. The stock market is far more complex than that.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to invest in the Windows Phone, then you go and find out who makes the Windows Phone i.e. Microsoft.

Then you go and decide if Windows Phone is successful will the share price of Microsoft go up (own research/deduction) and if you think that the price of Microsoft has a positive correlation with the Windows Phone, then you could buy shares of Microsoft.

There is no way to invest directly in individual products on stock exchanges, you are generally investing in the companies that produce them.

You find the ticker of a company by [googling.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=microsoft+stock+ticker) `NASDAQ: MSFT`